# Damaged macOS Mojave installer

Tags: macos, mojave

I downloaded the macOS Mojave installer on my 2015 MacBook Air. However, upon opening the installer, it gives this error message:

> This copy of the Install macOS Mojave application is damaged, and can‘t be used to install macOS.

Please do guide me on how to re-download this installer or any other method to install macOS Mojave on my MacBook.

Comment: you can try this link and download new copy (first delete the non working one) https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12

Comment: I solved it when I set the internet. It was able to verify the package and it was smooth after that.

Answer (score 20):

As per [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8561304) discussion on Apple support community, you should be able to overcome the issue by deleting `InstallInfo.plist` file from within the macOS Mojave installer app.

> 1. Go to your applications folder.
> 2. Find the installer for macOS Mojave.
> 3. Right click on the installer and click "Show Package Contents".
> 4. Click on folder named "Contents".
> 5. Click on the folder named "SharedSupport".
> 6. Delete the file named "InstallInfo.plist".
> 7. Enter your administer password to confirm.
> 8. Now open the installer.

Comment: Why does this work? Is `InstallInfo.plist"` broken? How come?

Comment: I tried many other solutions, and this is the only one that worked for my Mojave installation problem, which had a different error message: "An error occurred validating the installer data."

Answer (score 2):

It’s much more likely the certificate that signs the package is expired or there is damage to the contents of the installer, making it fail a tampering check.

- [Software update on obsolete system: is it real?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373461/software-update-on-obsolete-system-is-it-real)

Once you validate your mac is connected to the internet and the time is within 3 minutes or so of correct (closer is better) you can check the package or just download it again if that’s easier for you in most cases.

Comment: I deleted the original and re-downloaded from App Store.  Got the same error.