# Software update on obsolete system: is it real?

Tags: software-update, leopard, airport

I've got an old PowerPC Mac Mini running Leopard that I keep around to run legacy software.  Today, for the first time in years, Software Update opened up, offering to upgrade Airport Utility from 5.2.2 to 5.6.1.

Is this a genuine update, and if so, why is it showing up now, more than a decade after support for both the OS and the hardware ended?

Comment: I keep an old PowerMac around, too. I use it for open source development and testing. I provide remote SSH access to it for other developers. You can probably sidestep the UI and verify the update using the command line: `sudo softwareupdate --install --all`. My PowerMac just applied the AirPort Utility update.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is real, yes. A lot of older software updates (but also newer ones e.g. some 10.14.6 Supplemental Update from September 2019!) are signed with a certificate which becomes/became invalid on Oct, 24 2019.

To keep them in the update game the intermediate certificate authority and its certficates have been replaced – the payload stays the same – and they have been republished/reissued.

Further readings (with pics I don't want to deep-link here ):

1. [Beware Apple security certificates after 24 October: they may have expired](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/18/beware-apple-security-certificates-after-24-october-they-may-have-expired/)
2. [Certificate used to sign older Apple software expiring on October 24, 2019](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2019/10/16/certificate-used-to-sign-older-apple-software-expiring-on-october-24-2019/)

---

To check the validity of software installer packages use:

```
pkgutil --check-signature /path/to/package.pkg
```

Example (the OSInstall.pkg inside the InstallESD.dmg of Install macOS Sierra.app d/led on Feb, 26 2019):

```
pkgutil --check-signature /Volumes/OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/Packages/OSInstall.pkg 
Package "OSInstall.pkg":
   Status: signed by a certificate that has since expired
   Certificate Chain:
    1. Software Update
       SHA1 fingerprint: 1E 34 E3 91 C6 44 37 DD 24 BE 57 B1 66 7B 2F DA 09 76 E1 FD
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2. Apple Software Update Certification Authority
       SHA1 fingerprint: FA 02 79 0F CE 9D 93 00 89 C8 C2 51 0B BC 50 B4 85 8E 6F BF
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3. Apple Root CA
       SHA1 fingerprint: 61 1E 5B 66 2C 59 3A 08 FF 58 D1 4A E2 24 52 D1 98 DF 6C 60
```

To check dmgs use:

```
spctl -a -t open --context context:primary-signature -v /path/to/dmg
spctl -a -v /path/to/dmg
```

or

```
codesign -dvvv /path/to/dmg
```

Not all dmgs are codesigned! The precise command is sometimes macOS-version-dependent, or requires a min macOS/OS X version. Please check `man <command>` (eg: `man spctl`).

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, AFAIR it was the [first OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard#Security_enhancements) with code signing.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Apple's support pages](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1536), Airport Utility 5.6.1 was released back in June 2012. 
Why your Mac never noticed this update (or any of the others since 5.2.2) till now is a mystery. But it is a valid update.